# How to interpret and use generic vector?

Tags: java, generics, vector

Can any body explain this generic vector `Vector<? super Object> list = ...` and where to use it?

Comment: Most consider it deprecated. It's basically a synchronized List... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: `? super Object` is an Object really...

Comment: I wouldn't use Vector, I would use List and ArrayList.  I wouldn't use `? super Object` which is the same as `Object` as its plain confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are defining the **lower bound** of your unknown object `?`. So the `Vector<? super Object` can contain only `Object` and any super class of `Object`. But since `Object` does'nt have a super class it has no sense. It behaves same as `Vector<Object>`.

Refer [this sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html).

The counterpart for this is **upper bound** `Vector<? extends Object>` where you can add any object that extends `Object`.

You should be able to avoid using `Object` as the generic type is most cases.

Comment: Does it means if i have my own object it will be useful to use it?if yes how can it be useful? let say like this example: `List<? super MyObject> list = ...`

Comment: Yes. In that case you can add `MyObject` and any parent classes of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as

```
Vector<Object> list
```

Usually "? super Type" means that you can add supertypes of type Type

Object is the highest level in Java so there are no supertypes so the ? super is not needed

If it was

```
Vector<? extends Object> list
```

then it would mean that you can add any object that is a subclass of Object. This is every object in Java so it would be the same as

```
Vector<Object> list
```

Also consider List rather than Vector and if you want it thread safe then wrap it in Collections.synchronizedList(...)

Comment: `Vector<? extends Object>` is not the same as `Vector<Object>`.

Answer (score 3):

`<? super Object>` is absurd since there is no super type of Object, but it is allowed, and it consists of just Object types. http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html

Answer (score 1):

Such a list can only contain elements of type `Object` as Object doesn't have any super types similar to using extends of with an immutable class like String where such a collection can contain only Strings.